# Bootstrap 3 Complex Form Alignment

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, layout

[image: Form example]

Is this type of form alignment available out-of-the-box with Bootstrap 3? Would I use nested columns to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible using their grid system http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible, just make sure when you nest columns that you're nesting a row within the column. Since there is no code, here is a simple example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <!-- form content here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- table content here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <!-- large sidebar -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So to get the form elements to line up side-by-side in the middle section, would I put each form element in it's own column?